# Disable Row Selection in Telerik Rad Grid View

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, telerik-grid

Actually the problem is that i have created a stack panel in a Grid View Cell Template when i click on First item of Stack Panel then a white highlight appear at the top of cell .i want to remove it
Is there Any Solution for this ?
Thanks In Advance

**Here Is My Code**

```
 <telerikControls:GridViewDataColumn>
     <telerikControls:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,5" Height="Auto">
     <itimControls:Label Text="Qty/Value" Name="lblqty"  Width="90"       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></itimControls:Label>
     <itimControls:TextBox  Width="80"  Value="{Binding Qty,Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0,3,0,0" ></itimControls:TextBox>
     </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
     </telerikControls:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
     </telerikControls:GridViewDataColumn>
```

i cant share the picture of output due to Reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my last answer wasn't aware that you was using silver light until i read the tags, but this should work.

"To disable the selection functionality you can set the CanUserSelect to false."

Comment: Thanks @Adam ,But this Solution doesn't work in my scenario.is there any way to do it on any grid Event ??

Answer (score -1):

```
 <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView1" EnableRowVirtualization="False"/>
```

Comment: these solution didn't work .i have tried it .i explain our problem again on question .can you please review that and answer @ Jayasri